# Exclude sub domain rewrite non www to www in htacces

Tags: .htaccess, magento, subdomain

I'm having a Magento multistore setup and i'm sending all non www requests to www in the .htacces with the rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I'm using a sub domain for testing new websites and for this sub domain I don't need this rewrite. Therefore I use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [L]
```

Only problem now is that when I go to http:// sub.domain.com it works, but when I go to a category or product for example http:// sub.domain.com/cat1 or http:// sub.domain.com/product-red.html it doesn't work any more and I get a "Not Found" message.

What do I need to add to the code so it excludes the whole sub domain, including everything after the / ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a separate rule to ignore all requests for subdomain like that otherwise Magento's routing rule will also be skipped. Instead tweak your `www` rule like this to ignore subdomain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|sub)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot, this was causing me headaches. And what if I use more sub domains, like sub2.domain.com and sub3.domain.com? Will it become     (www|sub|sub2|sub3) ?

Comment: I have one more question. The magento setup is running on www.domain.com. The other storeviews have a different URL, like www.domain1.com. When I try sub.domain.com it works, but when I use the sub for another domain, like sub.domain1.com it redirects to www.domain.com.

And when I type test.domain3.com (a random subdomein that doesn't exist) it also goes to the fist domain where magento is installed, instead of to the 404 page. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: If `www` is to be added just for `domain.com` then you can have condition as: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\com$. [NC]` also.